# $A\subseteq B\to A\setminus B = \emptyset$. Is this true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\subseteq B$, is then $A\setminus B = \emptyset$?

If we take a some $x\in A$, then also $x\in B$. Right?

So, if we take all the elements of $B$ away from $A$, we have nothing left?

Comment: Yah. You are right.

Comment: Additionally, if you had $A$ is a subset of $B$ then 
$|B-A| \ge 0$

Comment: Don't know how to do B\A in the latex language. So I did B-A. :p

Comment: @randomgirl It's \setminus

Comment: some answers are also similar.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a somewhat nice way you can write up the proof for what you already know to be intuitively true. First you must know how $A\subseteq B$ and $A\setminus B$ are defined though. We have
$$
A\subseteq B = \{x : x\in A\to x\in B\}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
A\setminus B = \{x : x\in A\land x\not\in B\}\tag{2}
$$
Now consider the following argument.

**Claim:** $A\subseteq B\to A\setminus B=\emptyset$.

*Proof.* Suppose $A\subseteq B$ (we are given this). Then $x\in A\to x\in B$ by $(1)$. Consider the negation of $(1)$. That is, what is $\neg(x\in A\to x\in B)$? Note the following:
\begin{align} A\nsubseteq B &\equiv \neg(x\in A\to x\in B)\tag{definition}\\[0.5em] 
&\equiv \neg(x\not\in A\lor x\in B)\tag{$p\to q\equiv\neg p\lor q$}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv x\in A\land x\not\in B\tag{DeMorgan}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv A\setminus B.\tag{definition}
\end{align}
As you can see from the argument above, if we are given that $A\subseteq B$, then it must necessarily be true that $A\setminus B=\emptyset$. $\blacksquare$

This is just a more formal way of asserting what you noted at the beginning. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. $\qquad{}{}$

Comment: I think it does provide an answer to the question (rather clearly, in fact). And since one is not supposed to answer in comments, it should be given as an answer. As the OP has given the correct argument, I didn't think there was anything else to say.

Answer (score 0):

Well the definition of $A/ B$ is $A/B=A \cap B^c$. Since $A \subset B$ then $A \cap B^c=\emptyset$.